# How to avoid code duplication in similar templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I implemented a parallel_accumulate, similar to std::acumulate but using threads for parallelizing accumulation work.
There are two versions of std::accumulate, the second taking an additional operator for accumulation, while the first implicitly assumes addition.. first version:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
static T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
  unsigned long const length = std::distance(first, last);
  if (!length) return init;

  unsigned long const max_ths = 64;
  unsigned long const hw_ths = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  unsigned long const num_ths = std::min(hw_ths != 0 ? hw_ths : 2, max_ths);
  unsigned long const block_size = length / num_ths;
  std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_ths);
  Iterator block_start = first;

  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < num_ths; ++i) {
      Iterator block_end = block_start;
      std::advance(block_end, block_size);
      threads[i] = std::thread(                                 // diff1
                        _noop<Iterator,T>(),
                        block_start,
                        block_end,
                        std::ref(results[i]));
      block_start = block_end;
  }
  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

  return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init); // diff2
}
```

Second version:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T, typename BinOp>
static T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init, BinOp op)
{
  unsigned long const length = std::distance(first, last);
  if (!length) return init;

  unsigned long const max_ths = 64;
  unsigned long const hw_ths = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  unsigned long const num_ths = std::min(hw_ths != 0 ? hw_ths : 2, max_ths);
  unsigned long const block_size = length / num_ths;
  std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_ths);
  Iterator block_start = first;

  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < num_ths; ++i) {
      Iterator block_end = block_start;
      std::advance(block_end, block_size);
      threads[i] = std::thread(                                     // diff1
                        _op<Iterator,T,BinOp>(),
                        block_start,
                        block_end,
                        std::ref(results[i]));
      block_start = block_end;
  }
  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

  return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init, op); // diff2
}
```

As you can easily see my implementations of the two versions only differ on two lines, how would I avoid duplicating this code in C++ elegantly (i.e. not using #defines)?

(Note that I omitted _noop and _op for clarity, they are simply callable structs calling the respective versions of std::accumulate)

**Update:** I *want* to have the first version without an explicit addition operator (because the implicit std::accumulate is faster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have C++14 transparent operator functors, then the first version can be implemented as

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
static T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
    return parallel_accumulate(first, last, init, std::plus<>());
}
```

If you don't, the equivalent of `std::plus<>` is simply

```
struct my_plus {
    template<class T, class U>
    auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u)) {
        return std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I _want_ to call the implicit version in the first case, as it seems to be a lot faster.

Comment: @UnderFree Really? Did you turn on optimizations? This transparent functor should be as efficient as simple `+` with inlining.

Comment: You're right.. I somehow thought that it would do the inlining without me explicitly asking for optimizations. At least with -O3 the difference in running time was gone.. thanks!